# Accessing cookies in chrome incognito

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, security

I'm getting ready for a job interview regarding internet security,

Let's say I opened an incognito window in chrome and log into my gmail. I know that now I can access my google services (drive, gmail etc) from another window.

My question is, is it possible to copy cookies of incognito mode and merge them with normal mode? That would mean using incognito mode on someone else's computer would compromise my security ( if i'm not mistaken )

If it's possible please let me know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can authenticate by copying the cookie (token) in incognito mode. 
However, since the token has an expiration time, it will be blocked within a short time. also, in the case of incognito mode, all cookies (cache) are evaporated upon exit. so if you close the browser properly, it is difficult to cause security problems.

-> If you copy the cookie (token) to a separate storage space before it ends, you can use it before the expiration time. (1 hour for google, [google-auth](https://doc.corezoid.com/docs/google-oauth#:%7E:text=Timeout%20create%20token.-,According%20to%20the%20Google%20OAuth%20protocol%2C%20token%20expiration%20time%20is,cycle%20in%20the%20prescribed%20time.))